# Python, calculating lag of the center of the data

Tags: python, numpy, signals, distribution, lag

My two data sets are:

```
fnamerp1=([  93,   87,   96,   93,   90,  123,  111,   82,   87,  115,  103,
        101,   93,   92,  111,  107,  114,  106,  116,  106,  128,  115,
        141,  134,  120,  149,  140,  166,  152,  171,  192,  207,  227,
        266,  270,  286,  355,  385,  397,  488,  462,  531,  579,  622,
        711,  720,  801,  858,  906,  915,  915,  956, 1004, 1012, 1045,
        1076, 1063, 1013,  985,  924,  959,  838,  766,  763,  742,  642,
        587,  557,  484,  393,  353,  341,  284,  240,  221,  209,  147,
        109,  113,  102,   71,   63,   63,   50,   29,   39,   36,   25,
        30,   23,   27,   23,   19,   19,   24,   15,   23,   21,   26,
        15])

fnamerp2=([  105,  89, 120, 121, 103, 105, 113,  94, 104, 115, 122, 116, 121,
   129, 118, 126, 138, 146, 161, 163, 178, 192, 194, 222, 268, 272,
   285, 342, 380, 378, 373, 448, 493, 511, 571, 603, 691, 772, 738,
   796, 839, 832, 883, 930, 963, 975, 972, 931, 947, 941, 934, 964,
   871, 869, 826, 793, 733, 708, 606, 610, 515, 483, 409, 352, 358,
   264, 266, 205, 191, 167, 136, 138,  99, 102,  82,  57,  65,  53,
    51,  32,  26,  27,  39,  21,  29,  23,  25,  24,  16,  17,  27,
    33,  19,  13,  24,  26,  18,  22,  18,  20])
```

I want to find the lag between the center of the two peaks (not just their max). And my plan is to use `np.argmax(signal.correlate(fnamerp1,fnamerp2))`.

What is the right way to do this both from a mathematical perspective and also elegant in Python?

Comment: The data sets seem to be identical. Cross-correlation is a valid approach - make sure your signals are normalized.

Comment: Thanks for spotting my error. It is correct now.

Comment: A cheap ansatz is to fit a gaussian to each measurement and take the difference of the centers. See [here](http://python4esac.github.io/fitting/examples1d.html) for a fit example.